# Comparing pairs of rows for different data in one column within Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

**Context**

I have a spreadsheet in MS Excel 2010 that contains five columns and 5,361 rows of data (including the header row).

The table contains data pertaining to email addresses (where email addresses are listed in Column A). In total there are 2,680 email addresses, and by default the data is sorted in alphabetical order of email address so that rows 2 and 3 contain the same email address, rows 4 and 5 contain the same email address, and so on.

Column E contains a status value (where each value is a three word phrase). For example, the phrase may be "Active on TP", "Bounced on BAS", and so on. There are eight such status values, and for each row pertaining to the same email address it's **impossible** that the status value will match.

**The problem**

What I need to do is have a way to identify those email addresses for which **the first word of their status value do not match**.

For example, if cells E2 and E3 both have a status value commencing with the word "Active", or the word "Bounced", then these do not qualify. But if cell E2 had a value of "Active on TP" and cell E3 had a value of "Bounced on BAS", then these do qualify.

Below is a dummy screenshot showing examples of what qualifies or not:

[image]

As you can see, email addresses 2 and 4 meet the criteria because their two status values (in Column E) **do not start** with the same word.

**What I've already tried**

Without listing all my various attempts in detail, I've tried using `COUNTIF` formulas, adding a 'helper' column, using a Pivot Table and playing with conditional formatting.

I'm also thinking of biting the bullet to merge the two rows for each unique email address into one row with more columns, but I'm not sure if that will help me get to my end goal. Also, this is a once off analysis I need to do as I'm in the process of establishing a central data source and a dashboard, so I want to avoid going to that level of effort if at all possible.

**My question**

How do I easily identify the email addresses which meet my criteria (or conversely, those that don't meet the criteria)?

Comment: Your issue can be solved using helper column but while highlighting it needs little trick,, so if you want to try just reply through comments ☺

Comment: Thanks @RajeshS you've piqued my curiosity and I'd love to give it a try. :)

Comment: ,, check the answer I've posted and read **NB** part properly ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a column to show which rows have different values in column D. (This might be cheating, if it's important to look at column E instead. Let me know.)

The formula could be

```
=IF(A2=A1,IF(D2<>D1,TRUE,""),"")
```

or merely

```
=IF(A2=A1,D2<>D1,"")
```

These will give

[image: cropped screenshot of sample spreadsheet showing the results of the first formula: TRUE appears next to non-duplicates, while empty strings appear next to everything else.]

and

[image: cropped screenshot of sample spreadsheet showing the results of the second formula: TRUE appears next to non-duplicates, FALSE next to duplicates, and empty strings next to the other row of each pair.]

respectively.

I'd say the first is better for reading, the second for filtering. (Note that when you filter, the status bar—in Excel 2013, at any rate—shows the count of rows the filter is showing.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a go today and will let you know how I go. :)

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked well and I was able to get to my ultimate outcome. :) Looking at it now, not sure how I didn't even think to use Column D for my source values! LOL

Answer (score 1):

*Your issue can be solved using Helper Column:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Column `H` is Helper Column.
- Enter this formula in Cell `H10` & fill it
      down.

  `=IF(H8="","B",COUNTIF($F$9:$F9,F10))`

---

**N.B.**

- Formula returns `B` in Cell `H10`, since it's tricky part of this 
  exercise, otherwise if this Formula would have been used
  `=COUNTIF($F$9:$F9,F10)`,  returns `0` in Cell `H10`.
- Since I've used, value `0` & `3` to identify Rows doesn't match, therefore Cell `H10` needs to be manged (since usual `Counif` returns `0`).
- *Instead of First Words in Column `G`, I've used Column `F` because, data there are similar to every first word Column `G` does have.*

---

- Select required Rows in Column `G`.
- Reach to **Condition Formatting** then **New Rule** and apply this Formula,

[image]

- Apply an appropriate Color & finish with **Ok**.
- You may hide Helper Column.

*Adjust cell references as needed.*

Comment: +1 for this. It works as described and I'm sure I'll use this approach for other uses. Thanks for taking the time to explain it! :)

Comment: @Monomeeth, glad to help,, you may accept this as Answer too.

Comment: This does not give the correct result. The formulae doesn't attempt to compare the first words _for the same email address_, which was a requirement. Instead, it counts occurrences of the current first words in _all rows to that point_. From the results of this incorrect analysis, a cherry-picked set of values (zero and three) is then hard-coded into conditional formatting rules. Why 3? Why B? Why to that point? (Disclosure: I wrote [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1457658). If I am constrained by conflict-of-interest ethics to say nothing, I can recuse myself from these comments.)

Comment: @MathieuK. object is to compare 1st word of rows in Col. E, since Col D does have similar data so the wise step was to use it and I've expressed every possible reason,, read the **NB** section !!